# Syntax Error in Typescript: Unexpected Token "/" in JSON at position x (JSON with Comments)

Tags: json, typescript, compilation

Recently, I've pondered using comments in JSON files and discovered JSON with Comments in VSCode.
[image]

I switched my JSON files to JSON with Comments. That didn't create any trouble.

However, when I compile, it shows the error:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1170
    throw err;
    ^

SyntaxError: C:\...\data\materialData.json: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 7
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.Module._extensions..json (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1167:22)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:94:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Jack\Documents\Jacks_Workshop\Coding\DiscordBot_v4\jsons.js:17:43)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
```

Here is my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "strict": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

VSCode isn't actually compiling your code. It assumes you are pre-compiling or pre-parsing your json.

Your version of Node is compiling your program and Node doesn't support comments in JSON out of the box. You will need an external library for that:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonminify

In the project root, run this on the command line:

```
npm install jsonminify
```

Then require the library in your .js file and replace any `JSON.parse(myJSONString)` statements with `JSON.parse(jsonminify(myJSONString))`

Example from the jsonminify README.md:

```
var jsonminify = require("jsonminify");

jsonminify('{"key":"value"/** comment **/}')
>> '{"key":"value"}'

JSON.minify('{"key":"value"/** comment **/}')
>> '{"key":"value"}'
```